# Data not enter in input fields

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Actually, I have a website where I want to run the complete process of cart functionality. All is going well but when I click on Payment method and select Debit card and put data in field it not accept. How can I put data into fields.

`WebElement BilMethod = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath
("/html/body/app-root/div/app-checkout/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/ng-stepper/div/div[2]/div[2]/app-address/div/div[3]/div[3]/div/div")));
BilMethod.click();
Thread.sleep(1000);

```
    //Clicking on Next Button
    WebElement Clicknext = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath
            ("/html/body/app-root/div/app-checkout/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/ng-stepper/div/div[2]/div[2]/app-address/div/div[5]/div[2]/button")));
    Clicknext.click();
    Thread.sleep(10000);
    
    //Clicking on Credit card Method
    WebElement creditcard = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath
            ("/html/body/app-root/div/app-checkout/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/ng-stepper/div/div[2]/div[3]"
                    + "/app-payment/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/ngx-paypal/div/div/iframe[1]")));
    creditcard.click();
    System.out.println("We have selected Credit card method");
    ` Code is working till there butt
```

`//Entering card details
WebElement Card_No = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div/form/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div")));
Card_No.sendKeys("5105105105105100");

```
    WebElement  expirydate = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("expiry-date")));    
    expirydate.sendKeys("1225");
    
    WebElement cvc = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("credit-card-security")));
    cvc.sendKeys("123");
}`
```

Website Link: https://vapesuite.allomate.solutions

Comment: Till what line does your code work and what isn't work as expected? What error do you get there?

Comment: Yes I can click on payment method butt when I click on payment method the form is display, then the problem is start input fields not get data.

Comment: @cruisepandey : It's not working, do you have any other solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See, here you are trying to click on an iframe (Check the last part of xpath):

```
//Clicking on Credit card Method
 WebElement creditcard = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath
            ("/html/body/app-root/div/app-checkout/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/ng-stepper/div/div[2]/div[3]"
                    + "/app-payment/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/ngx-paypal/div/div/iframe[1]")));
    creditcard.click();
```

it should not be done like this, you should always switch to an iframe :

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.xpath("//iframe[contains(@name, 'zoid__paypal_buttons')]")));
```

and then click on debit or credit card  :

```
WebElement debitCreditCardButton = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//span[text()='Debit or Credit Card']")));
debitCreditCardButton.click();
```

Additionally once clicked on **debit or credit card** button , I see there's a new window popping up :

first switch to `default content` like this :

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

and then switch to newly opened windows :

```
ArrayList<String> windows = new ArrayList<String>(driver.getWindowHandles());
driver.switchTo().window(windows.get(1));
        
// fill credit cards details now
```

**Update 1 : (In sequence)**

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.xpath("//iframe[contains(@name, 'zoid__paypal_buttons')]")));
WebElement debitCreditCardButton = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//span[text()='Debit or Credit Card']")));
debitCreditCardButton.click();
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
                
ArrayList<String> windows = new ArrayList<String>(driver.getWindowHandles());
driver.switchTo().window(windows.get(1));
```

**Update 2 :**

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.xpath("//iframe[contains(@name, 'zoid__paypal_buttons')]")));
        WebElement debitCreditCardButton = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//span[text()='Debit or Credit Card']")));
        debitCreditCardButton.click();
        driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
        ArrayList<String> windows = new ArrayList<String>(driver.getWindowHandles());
        driver.switchTo().window(windows.get(1));
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("firstName"))).sendKeys("Zaman 10");
```

Comment: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression "//iframe[contains(@name, 'zoid__paypal_buttons')]" because of the following error:
TypeError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The result is not a node set, and therefore cannot be converted to the desired type.
  (Session info: chrome=91.0.4472.77).

Comment: After trying your method, it shows the above error.

Comment: Can you show me what part you have included from my solution

Comment: WebElement creditcard = (WebElement) wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.xpath("\"//iframe[contains(@name, 'zoid__paypal_buttons')]\"")));
creditcard.click();
System.out.println("We have selected Credit card method");
  
Thread.sleep(5000);
  
WebElement debitCreditCardButton = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//span[text()='Debit or Credit Card']")));
debitCreditCardButton.click();

Comment: The above code i added from your solution

Comment: Instead of `WebElement creditcard = (WebElement) wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.xpath("\"//iframe[contains(@name, 'zoid__paypal_buttons')]\"")))` --- use this `wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.xpath("//iframe[contains(@name, 'zoid__paypal_buttons')]")));`

Comment: You don't have to do `creditcard.click();` cause that's an iframe. If you want to click on credit card or debit card... use this `WebElement debitCreditCardButton = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//span[text()='Debit or Credit Card']")));
debitCreditCardButton.click();` but make sure to switch to iframe using the above code first.

Comment: In xpath expression why do we have \ remove that it should be exactly same as I have put in the above comment

Comment: Your above solution is working fine, but it not accepts input.

Comment: Cause you still have not switch to new windows

Comment: I have updated the code in update section 1 : after that try to enter inputs

Comment: After `debitCreditCardButton.click();` you have to do `driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
                
ArrayList<String> windows = new ArrayList<String>(driver.getWindowHandles());
driver.switchTo().window(windows.get(1));` and after this send the inputs... I don't see you are using the mentioned code

Comment: There is a problem sometime window open and sometine form show in dropdown.

Comment: Do we have any solution when form is open in drop down.

Comment: You can use if and else clause.. like if window is shown then do this stuff else if form is shown then do some other stuff

Comment: But your provided solution is not working for window as well. Not locate ID of field.

Comment: what id u passed show me your code along with errorStackTrace

Comment: May be a full window works.. check out the update 2 code

Comment: Full window works and your input is working, butt it not accepted card info. Can you please check

Comment: What code you are using for that ? Don't mix too many question in a single question... If this worked close this ticket by accepting it and create a new ticket instead

Comment: wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("credit-card-number"))).sendKeys("5105105105105100");
  
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("expiry-date"))).sendKeys("1225");
   
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("credit-card-security"))).sendKeys("123");

Comment: Use this `wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("cardNumber"))).sendKeys("102002020220");`